# When Passing Values Into a Query Using a Macro, Can You Continue the Query When the Value Doesn't Exist?

Tags: sql, oracle, error-handling, sas, macros

I have a query in which I am passing in a long list of variables using a macro. I'm also using a macro to run that same query for different tables. After running the macro, I found that not all of the tables contain all the the variables listed. Technically, the tables are supposed to have the same columns but it appears some of them are missing from some tables. My question is...can I get the query to bypass that particular macro "passed-in" value if the value doesn't exist?  For example, if I have 10 tables that should all have the same 3 variables (model, make, & year) but one of them doesn't have the variable "make", can it smart pass this and continue on?  So, as a recap, the macro &&&PROV&FT contains a long list of variables. When a table doesn't contain one or more of those variables, can I skip over the one it doesn't have using an error handler of some sort?  Is there a GO option I can use?

I can drop the column that isn't common between all the tables from the macro list but would prefer not to since the majority of the tables have it.

```
%macro NULCNT() / parmbuff; 
    %do i = 1 %to %sysfunc(countw(%bquote(&syspbuff.))); 
        %let ST = %scan(%bquote(&syspbuff.), &i.);

CREATE TABLE CHI_&ST._PRO_&FT AS
select *
from connection to oracle
  (SELECT COUNT(*) AS TOT_TBL_CNT, &&&PROV&FT)  
   from DBSCHEMA.&ST._TBL_&FT A);

      %end;
%mend NULCNT;

PROC SQL;
connect to oracle();
%NULCNT(&STATES);
disconnect from oracle;
QUIT;
```

I get an error that the column doesn't exist in one of the tables.

Comment: Your program is reading data from Oracle. Sounds more like an ORACLE quesition instead of a SAS question.

Comment: Can you can explain the actual problem this code is trying to solve in more detail? It might be easier to do the testing for which tables have which variables BEFORE getting to the step of being ready to generate code.  What were the original inputs? The list of variables to include in the query? The list of tables to query? Both?

Comment: Hello Tom.  It's a little difficult to explain but I'll try.  I previously made a table that contains all the distinct columns from some tables in a schema that are supposed to have the exact same structure and concatenated some text of COUNT() around the columns. Then I put those INTO: a macro so that I could call on all the variables in my code above and it would give me the count.  My ultimate goal is to identify the percentage of nulls for each column in the table for a data quality assessment. The code and all the macros work thus far except this one issue where we are realizing that the

Comment: tables in the schema that were supposed to have the same columns...don't. Meaning that there are 1 or more that are missing a column because the customer didn't submit things properly. So when I run &&&PROV&FT, I get the error that a certain column does not exist in one or more of the source tables.  So I was just wondering if there was a way to continue on to the next column automatically. I know that I can create an individual  macro that stores just the columns for each specific table but that sort of defeats what I was trying to do.  It's hard to explain here but I also had to do prep work

Comment: to account for different &FT, different &ST, and the related columns. So, I probably make all that as clear as mud. Lol.  It's hard to explain very well.  Sorry.  I mainly just want to know if there is a macro error handler or function that will continue the macro anyway and move on to the next column after one of them "isn't found in the source table". Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What about getting a list of columns in each table and then compare against your list:

```
proc contents data = DBSCHEMA.&ST._TBL_&FT out = cols;
run;

proc sql;
  select name into :cols  separated by ' ' from work.cols;
quit;
```

This will give you the columns that are present in the particular table into a macro variable cols.

Then in your loop you could create another list that has only the columns that you specified that are in &cols also and pass them into PROC SQL. Essentially an intersection between &cols and &&&PROV&FT.

This can be accomplished with the following code:

```
  %let this_cols =;
  %let ii = 1;

  /* Assuming &&&PROV&FT is comma separated based on the way you use it */
  %do %while(%scan(&&&PROV&FT, &ii, %str(,)) ne %str());
    %let this = %scan(&&&PROV&FT, &ii, %str(,));
    %let found =  %sysfunc(indexw(&cols, &this));
    %if &found ne 0 %then %do;
      %if (&this_cols ne %str()) %then %do;
        %let this_cols = &this_cols.,&this;
      %end;
      %else %do;
        %let this_cols = &this;
      %end;
    %end;
    %let ii = %eval(&ii + 1);
  %end;
```

Now you can use &this_cols instead of &&&PROV&FT in your SQL statement.

Answer (score 0):

Just drive the process from the ACTUAL variables in the datasets.  So get a list of the variables in the datasets, for example with PROC CONTENTS, and filter to the subset of variables of interest.  Then drive the code generation from the dataset, not from macro variables.

So you might first want to create a macro that takes as input the member name and a space delimited list of variable names.

```
%macro nullcnt(memname,varlist);
...
%mend;
```

Then get the dataset with the list of actual variables of interest.

```
%let vars_of_interest=AGE HEIGHT WEIGHT ;
proc contents data=mylib._all_ noprint out=contents; run;
data want ;
  set contents;
  where findw(name,"&vars_of_interest",' ','i');
  keep memname name;
run;
```

And use it to generate calls to the macro.

```
data _null_;
  set want ;
  by memname ;
  if first.memname then call execute(cats('%nrstr(%nullcnt)(',memname,','));
  call execute(' '||trim(name));
  if last.memname then call execute(')');
run;
```